# Creating subLayers using CARTO JS v4.1.8

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-js, cartocss, css

I created a simple map with multiple layers using the below code.

```
this.cartoSource = new carto.source.SQL(sql);
this.layerStyle  = new carto.style.CartoCSS(layerStyle);
this.layer = new carto.layer.Layer(this.cartoSource, this.layerStyle , layerOption);
```

Whenever there is a change in the source or firing `feature_cover` event, all map layers are repainted (a kind of flickering). why does a layer affect another independent layer?

My requirements are I have a layer with polygon shape. Whenever a user hovers over a particular polygon, that feature should be highlighted without repainting or flickering.

I tried two different ways:

1. I was updating layer style using `setContent` with the following
   code:

```
    #layer[cartodb_id=123]
            { 
                line-opacity: 1; 
                line-color: #FFF; 
                line-width: 1; 
                polygon-fill: #f4c650; 
            }
```

2. I was using another layer with one sql source with where
   condition where `cartodb_id = FEATURE_OVER.data.cartodb_id`.

Both are getting a flickering effect. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I got the solution. The problem was, I was reusing the carto client for all the layers. Thats the reason. It was affecting all of them.

Comment: Please @user146810 if you had the solution to your own question, you have to post it as an answer.